# MVC routing null parameters error when i use two map-route on the same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

I tried to use map route on my mvc project,first route "route1" is working fine with two parameters 
http://localhost:43601/records/index/1/5454546

now the second route - on the same controller - recordcontroller- is NOT working "route2" 
http://localhost:43601/records/attachmentdetails/828/2
and gave an error:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'attId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AttachmentDetails(Int32, Int32)'

any help please?

```
//route code 
routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            //Web API
            routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
            routes.MapRoute(
        name: "route1",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{libId}/{recordNo}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Records", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
            routes.MapRoute(
           name: "route2",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{attId}/{atype}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Records", action = "AttachmentDetails", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
                routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
            routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default4",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{attId}/{atype}",
           defaults: new { controller = "FileManager", action = "BookAttachmnt", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
//controllers code
public ActionResult Index(string libId, int recordNo = 0)
        {
}
public ActionResult AttachmentDetails(int attId, int atype)
        {
            BasicSearchAttribute();
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: As a side issue, remove `id = UrlParameter.Optional` if there is no parameter called `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching `route1` when you really want to match `route2`.

To achieve this, use this route instead, and put it **before** `route1`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "route2",
       url: "Records/{action}/{attId}/{atype}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Records", action = "AttachmentDetails", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

The reason your code isn't working is that routes are matched 'top down' (i.e. the order in which they are defined). The URL you are using meets the rules for `route1` **before** it meets the rules for `route2`. Alas, `route1` has different parameter names (`libId` rather than `attId`) and thus the routing fails since your action wants a `attId` parameter, but was **given** a `libId` parameter.

But putting the above route **first** it will mean that it gets used, rather than `route1`. Note also that I have hard-coded `Records` in the route, to ensure that URLs that start with `Records` are handled by `route2` and **everything else** is handled by `route1` (or later routes).

Comment: Have a look at `{controller}/{action}/{libId}/{recordNo}` You've said 'match any URL I get with 4 parts'. Then you passed it a URL with 4 parts. So the routing said 'sweet, I'll use that route'. Does that make sense? Now, the problem is, you don't **want** it to use that route. So you need **more specific routes**. That is why I used `url: "Records`. I am saying 'only match this URL **if it starts with Records**'. _Now, `route2` needs to be **before** `route1` because it goes with the **first match**. So we need to ensure it matches `route2` before it knows about `route1`._